# Parsing Json Array in PHP with keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wanted to parse the data array with the given path ($path), where each one is key in json Array.

```php
$data['system']['local']['version'] = 1;
$path = "system.local.version";

$key_array = explode(".", $path); 

foreach ( $key_array as $keys) {
    if( !array_key_exists($keys,$data)) {
        return -1;
    }

    $data = $data[$keys];
}

print_r($data);
```

PS : I need complete path after traversing the json array with givenn path (keys).

ex : - what i want after traversing the array ( Expected output from above code).

```php
Array
(
    [system] => Array
        (
            [local] => Array
                (
                    [version] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This question sounds a bit confused. The first line of your code already generates the array structure you want. Also, at no point is JSON used, so I'm not sure how that is relevant.

Comment: first line is just getting after json_decode($data,true)
Its an json array.

Comment: to whom do you `return` outside of function ?

Comment: You need to explain what you want from the output. If it is what you said in the "expected output" code block then you simply use: $data['system']['local']['version'] = 1; then print_r($data); or print_r($data,true); if you want to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Return is not a question here Viral,
I need to store the array structure while traversing the path with keys.
Above I am just losing it with scalar assignment.

Comment: @dk08 I need to store the array structure while traversing the path with keys. Above I am just losing it with scalar assignment. Basedon the keys I am traversing and validating the json array.

Comment: So you want to reference a value in an array similar to the way XPath works with XML?

Comment: yes... somewhat similar... in our case xpath is the $path using which we are trying to traverse and extract the value in $data(which is a global json array)....

Comment: How about [this](http://ideone.com/OGTUno)?